# Change images dynamically on a web page without store them in the server first [Javascript/Jquery - Spring]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, spring

I have a web page with three images which will change with a user click on one of them. Since the original image is an ImagePlus object, I have to do some calculation with a Java class I have.
What I am doing now is the following:

User click --> Ajax call for the computation of the new images --> Store resulting images in the server --> load the new images in the web page

I know this is bad way to work, so I would like to change the images in the web page dynamically without save them in the server first. This should improve the performance of the whole system.

Can you help me please?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

make you ajax request be serve by servlet returning image as stream, but not forget to set content type as in below for ex.:

```
response.setContentType("image/jpg");
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.
However, I am already doing like so, but with a File as input.

`
   response.setContentType("image/jpg");
   OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();   
   FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(url);  
   int size = in.available();  
   byte[] content = new byte[size];  
   in.read(content);  
   out.write(content);  
   in.close();  
   out.close();
`

But I need to do this with an ImagePlus as input.
So, I need a way to convert ImagePlus to InputStream or something like this.